# Why does NumberFormat.format throw an NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, number-formatting

I've just found a very strange `NullPointerException`. First, I create a `NumberFormat` like this (note that the default `Locale` would be Germany, I don't know if that helps):

```java
NumberFormat angleFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.UK);
angleFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
angleFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
```

Then, I tried to format a double with it. This is done with a new Thread created by a Lambda, while `angleFormat` is declared at the method containing the Lambda. The code where the Exception is thrown looks like this:

```java
con.println("D" + moveId + (state.isEnemyInSightOf(e) ? "+" : "-")
        + angleFormat.format(e.getAngle()) // line 123 - error is here
        + (state.isMissileInSightOf(e) ? "+" : "-")
        + angleFormat.format(e.getSight())
        + (e.getLastShot() >= 10 || e.getLastShot() <= -1 ? "+" : "-")
        + angleFormat.format(e.getLives()));
```

`e.getAngle()` returns a `double`, so it can't return null. However, I get this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.fastDoubleFormat(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.fastFormat(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at server.game.Simulator.lambda$0(Simulator.java:123)
    at server.game.Simulator$$Lambda$3/23162747.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**I'm sure that `e` isn't null because of the Exception's stacktrace, it would a) be thrown one line earlier and b) not at `java.text.DecimalFormat.fastDoubleFormat`**

Why is there a `NullPointerException` beeing thrown **sometimes**, and sometimes it works without problems? And what does that mean? The error seems to be reproducable, but not very often.

Comment: what is he line 123?

Comment: `"NullPointerException beeing thrown sometimes, and sometimes it works without problems? And what does that mean?"` -- this intermittent error smells of a threading issue. Is this a GUI? Are you careful with your code's threading?

Comment: Are you sure `e` itself is not `null`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, this is a server without a gui, and this is a new thread, but I'm sure that e could not be modified while running the thread

Comment: @Mureinik Then the Exception would be thrown one line earlier

Comment: @dasblinkenlight First of all, please read the exception stack trace, and second, please read my code, the exception would be thrown one line earlier if `e` was null

Comment: @BalusC `angleFormat` is declared at the method that contains the lambda, and it is effectively final

Comment: You are not using the same instance of `NumberFormat` concurrently without synchronization, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I create the threads in a loop with each one a different `e` but the same `NumberFormat`, but why should this cause a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @msrd0 This *shouldn't* create an NPE, but it definitely *could*, because class designers went to the trouble of mentioning explicitly that the access is to be synchronized externally: *If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.* I can only speculate that there is some internal buffer management going on, so if you catch it in a bad state, you could get an NPE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **From the comments:** I create the threads in a loop with each one a different `e` but the same `NumberFormat`

This appears to be the source of intermittent issues that your code is experiencing. According to the [documentation of `NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), the class is not thread-safe, so concurrent access must be synchronized externally:

> Number formats are generally not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDoc for `DecimalFormat`

> Synchronization
>
> Decimal formats are generally not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

By the way, which version of Java is this?  I don't see a `DecimalFormat.fastFormat()` method in the docs for either Java 6 or 7.

Comment: Since I mentioned in the question that I use Lambdas, I'm using Java8